# How do you disable cookies in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I've tried disabling cookies in Internet Explorer 7, I've changed the settings under Internet Options->Privacy and this did nothing, when I reloaded the page.

I read somewhere that you need to restart IE7, than physically delete the Internet cache and cookie files first, and finally reload your page to disable cookies.  (I also had no luck with this, cookies are still present, as evidenced by my script still reacting as though cookies are loaded.)

Um I guess I should also note that IE asks me if I wish to enable an ActiveX component when I access the page I have created.  I don't have any ActiveX components on the page, but I'll take this to mean I have Javascript on the page.

I know my script works because when I disable cookies in other browsers (FF3 and Safari) it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: And how is this programming-related?

Comment: I'm programming cookies, and I wrote a script to make a site do nothing if cookies are disabled.  However if they are enabled, (and no cookies from the site are set) a window is displayed asking the user to join the company mailing list.  (client's idea). If they've visted the site before, no window

Comment: The ActiveX warning shouldn't be triggered by JS. But it might be triggered if you have some <object> tag somewhere.

Comment: @PhiLho - IE does spit up the ActiveX warning when the only outside or external thing is JavaScript. Depends on security level though.

Answer (score 1):

IE's cookie settings control panel applies to the Internet Zone only.

To disable cookies in other zones, use the IE8 developer toolbar (hit F12) and choose "Disable Cookies" from the menu.

Comment: He'll have a hard time pulling up the IE8 developer toolbar on IE7.

Comment: Obviously.  But debugging in IE7 is so limited compared to IE8 that an upgrade is certainly in order.

Comment: A browser upgrade is not always an option when you are working for a client the refuses to upgrade.

Comment: @leeand00: Of course not. However, the original poster asked a developer/testing question. I haven't heard of clients that refuse to allow the developers themselves to use other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Does what's explained over [here](http://www.ardmorewhisky.com/terms/cookies.html) and [here](http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/cookies.htm) help?

Comment: I tried that stuff, does it have anything to do with maybe the fact that the page I'm developing exists on the local machine?

Comment: (i.e. Not on a webserver...sadly, it's a static page)

Comment: Really have no idea, and don't want to mislead you by saying 'probably'. :)

Comment: If you're using the FILE protocol to open a file on the local machine, then yes, this is the "Local Machine Lockdown" security setting. You can disable it using the "Allow Active Content to run in files on my computer" checkbox inside Tools > Internet Options > Advanced, but you shouldn't browse the untrusted web with that set.